# Filter ProcessInstance by Id Type

Tags: apex, soql

I'm writing a short snippet of code to get which records of a certain type were approved, and by who. However, I don't have an id list- I have an sObject type. I know I can filter the id values after the query with something like:

`if (String.valueOf(processInstance.TargetObjectId).startsWith('006')) { ... }`

But, I'd rather filter these values out in a query instead of having to do it in apex. I tried using the `LIKE` keyword to filter the query, as below:

`SELECT Status, TargetObjectId FROM ProcessInstance WHERE TargetObjectId LIKE '006%'`

But this query fails with:

> **INVALID_QUERY_FILTER_OPERATOR**
>
> [object Object]: TargetObjectId FROM ProcessInstance WHERE TargetObjectId LIKE '006%' LIMIT ^ ERROR at Row:1:Column:58 invalid operator on id field

I know the docs say the `LIKE` operator can only be used with `String` types, but I was under the impression that the `Id` type was just a wrapper over the `String` type. Is there any way I can get this filter working inside a soql query?

Comment: are you open to using an IN operator, you can prepare a list of records and use TargetobjectId IN : List_of_Ids

Comment: That would require me to run a second query before this one- which is an option, but the only fields I need are the `TargetObjectId` and the `Status` from the `ProcessInstance`, so I'd rather construct the objects from the single query.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `TargetObject.Type` instead.

```
SELECT Status, TargetObjectId FROM ProcessInstance WHERE TargetObject.Type = 'Opportunity'
```

See [Understanding Polymorphic Keys and Relationships](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.soql_sosl.meta/soql_sosl/sforce_api_calls_soql_relationships_and_polymorph_keys.htm):

> ### Using the Type qualifier
>
> You can use the Type qualifier on a field to determine the object type that’s referenced in a polymorphic relationship. Use the Type qualifier in the `WHERE` clause of a `SELECT` statement to conditionally control what’s returned from the query depending on the referenced object type. The following `SELECT` statement uses Type to filter the query based on the What field in Event.
>
> ```
> SELECT Id
> FROM Event
> WHERE What.Type IN ('Account', 'Opportunity')
> ```
>
> At run time this `SELECT` statement returns the IDs for Events that reference Accounts or Opportunities in the What field. If an Event referenced a Campaign in the What field, it wouldn’t be returned as part of this `SELECT`. Unlike the TYPEOF expression, object types are returned as strings from Type. You can apply any `WHERE` comparison operator to the object type strings, such as = (Equals) or `LIKE`.